# Cache audio files not working

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, caching, audio

I'm developing a canvas-based game.

Of course, sounds are an important part of any game. Sometimes, though, the same sound may play more than once at a time.

I already have code that checks if the desired sound is already playing and, if it is, creates a new sound with the same source and plays it. (And from then on alternates using the two sound elements until it needs to play three times at once, in which case it add another sound to the list, and so on)

However, the above method does cause quite some delay the first time a sound is needed more than once at a time, so to alleviate this I want to preload the same sound in anticipation of it being used more than once at a time.

I've set up a loop of sorts where it will add one of the preloads, then when that's done it adds the next one, etc. This allows me to preload a bunch of sounds without interrupting other HTTP activity (which could be needed for the game).

However, I notice that it's fetching the sound from the server every time, even though the sound has already been loaded.

Here's the headers being sent by the server:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2013 20:16:44 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4
>   Last-Modified: Wed, 10 Jul 2013 12:58:44 GMT
>   ETag: "209f80-5121-4e127d668a900"
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   Content-Length: 20769
>   Cache-Control: max-age=29030400, public
>   Expires: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 20:16:44 GMT
>   X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
>   Connection: close
>   Content-Type: audio/mpeg

As you can see I have a cache-control header, which works fine for images and scripts, but for some reason it's not being used for sounds. The browser is requesting them anew every time.

Help? =D

EDIT: Okay, now the browser seems to be using the cache for the first time the sounds are loaded, but each subsequent load queries the server instead. Erm.....

EDIT 2: Chrome seems to be handling this just fine. Looks like Internet Explorer is the one having the problem.

Comment: Per your edits - are you seeing the same behavior for images/scripts? Or do they continuously work as expected in non-IE?

Comment: @Ian Images and scripts are coming back with `304` responses as I would expect them to. That said the server is still being hit for them. Is there any way to tell the browser to not check with the server?

Comment: Which IE version exactly? Generally speaking, you shouldn't see this problem; I don't see this with the Pirates Love Daisies game, for instance. Got a repro URL? You're not loading this page from a page with a META REFRESH tag, are you?

Comment: Using IE10. The server's currently behind an HTTP authentication since the project is still in alpha stages, so I'm afraid I can't show a demo page.

Comment: What headers are being sent by the client?